What exactly makes simulating a $T$-gate difficult?
Consider the circuit below which implements the T-gate on the state $\vert\psi\rangle$ via gate teleportation.

Let $\vert\psi\rangle$ be a stabilizer state so that we can efficiently keep track of its evolution through Clifford gates. Note that $\vert\psi\rangle$ could be entangled with other registers in the circuit but the full state of all the registers can still be assumed to be a stabilizer state. The Z measurement in green is a single bit that is $0$ or $1$ and determines whether we apply the S-gate or not.
What part of simulating this classically is hard? If we know whether or not the S-gate should be applied to $\vert\psi\rangle$, then in both cases, the circuit is Clifford and we can efficiently continue to simulate it. The output continues to be a stabilizer state and we can therefore simulate any future Clifford gates trivially and T-gates through the same idea here - the question is only whether an S-gate was applied or not each time.
This leads me to conclude that knowing whether or not to apply the S-gate is the bit that is hard to compute classically. However, if we have a compact description of $\vert\psi\rangle$ (which we do because it is a stabilizer state) and we know that $\vert T\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\vert 0\rangle + e^{i\pi/4}\vert 1\rangle)$, is it hard to compute the probabilities associated with the green measurement outcome?
One more piece that may be relevant is that the decision to apply the S-gate in the case shown here only depends on the probabilities associated with the green measurement. However, in a circuit with many T-gates, there may be correlations between different green measurements and hence the decision to apply/not apply the S-gate cannot be decided individually.
TL;DR: which bit exactly prevents us from treating the entire circuit as if it were Clifford circuit?

I think, you almost answered the question yourself. Maybe it helps to specify the output of the computation, that is typically the measurement of some observable. How many Clifford circuits do you need to simulate to get a good estimate of the output? The answer should scale exponentially in the number of T gates. Even though calculating one "trajectory" might be efficient, the whole sampling problem isn't.

@RefikMansuroglu, yes I'm trying to pinpoint the exact place that creates this exponential blowup. Is it the correlations in the many green measurements that is the problem? Or is it computing any single green measurement that is the problem? Or both/something else? Thanks!

TL;DR: We only know how to efficiently simulate the action of Clifford circuits on inputs that are stabilizer states. The input to the above circuit includes a magic state and hence is not a stabilizer state.

The input to the CNOT gate is a product $|\psi\rangle\otimes|T\rangle$ of a stabilizer state $|\psi\rangle$ and a non-stabilizer (magic) state $|T\rangle$. Hence, the output of the CNOT gate is a non-stabilizer state. Consequently, a standard Clifford simulator is unable to apply the CNOT gate since it cannot even represent its input in the form of a tableau.
It is possible to extend a Clifford simulator so that it can pull through here, e.g. by making it store two tableaus and two complex amplitudes. A Clifford simulation extended this way can represent arbitrary superpositions of two stabilizer states, including all states that arise in the above circuit. However, this simulator will fail following a second T gate, because it will then have to store a superposition of four stabilizer states.
Perhaps the misunderstanding arises from the assumption that measuring out the target qubit in the post-CNOT state somehow turns the state of the control qubit back into a stabilizer state. It doesn't. For example, if $|\psi\rangle=|+\rangle$ (which a stabilizer state), then after the measurement but before the $S$ correction the control qubit is either $|T\rangle$ or $S^\dagger|T\rangle$ (neither of which is a stabilizer state) depending on measurement outcome.
